# ¿cómo se hace un apetición a API externa con PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, api

He intentado hacer una petición con AJAX a una API meteorológica pero me sale el error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Mi archivo está en local con XAMPP .

No he encontrado solución para realizar mi petición con AJAX y por lo visto debo añadir unas cabeceras y hacer la petición mediante PHP. Lo he intentado con cURL sin éxito  y me sale este otro error

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$url="url API";

//Iniciamos un recurso CURL en $c
$c = curl_init($url);

//Indicamos que nos devuelva la información capturada
//como la información de retorno
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Realizamos la llamada
$pagina = curl_exec($c);

//Cerramos el recurso (Liberamos memoria)
curl_close($c);


echo json_encode($pagina);
```

```js
       $.ajax({
        url: "url de Api o archivo.php",
        success:(function(data){
         console.log(data);
        }),
        error:(function() {
         console.log('ko');
        })
       });
```

Comment: La pagina  a la que intentas hacer la peticion ajax esta fuera de tu dominio y no tiene CORS activado por lo que no te permitira hacer las peticiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en las peticiones CORS por la misma cuestión que te menciono @einer. La solucione sta en que debes de descargar un complemento para el navegador sea Chrome(es más fácil) u otro de tu preferencia. Busca lo por ese nombre CORS y te ayudará, sólo tienes que ligar la dirección web a la que realizas tu petición con ajax. Y de esta manera permites la conexión entre ambas partes.

Ahora el documento esta codificado para evitar problemas de seguridad y poder ser usada desde una aplicación externa (Un dominio X a un dominio Y).

```
    <?php 
      //Permisos CORS

      //* es un comodin para desplegar la información a cualquier servidor que realice la peticion.
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 

      //Debemos dar permisos de acuerdo a la llamada o metodo que necesites GET,POST,UPDATE.
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

      //Para formatos JSON se debe asignar el encabezado correspondiente.
      header("Content-Type: application/json");

     ?>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero así arreglo el problema solo parcialmente, porque si subo el proyecto a un servidor y deja de estar el local, todos los navegadores que lo visiten necesitarán ese complemento, ¿no?

Comment: No necesariamente. mira, los datos que vienen vía AJAX tienen que pertenecer al mismo dominio. En el caso de que esto no sea así la aplicación no podrá cargar los datos por limitaciones de seguridad. Los problemas comienzan cuando nosotros tenemos aplicaciones que necesitan acceder a esos datos pero no se encuentran bajo el mismo dominio. Un ejemplo muy habitual es una aplicación Movil empaquetada con PhoneGAP o en Ionic 3 con Angular. Por lo que en el momento en que subas tu app a un servidor esta responderá de forma correcta, es solo una limitación cuando se está trabajando de forma local.

Comment: Aunque @crismf acabo de actualizar la respuesta para que tengas otra posible solucion (desde el servidor PHP), me avisas si te funciona.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la explicación. Ya tengo mi archivo.php trabajando :-) con las cabeceras y alojado en un servidor.

Comment: @crismf Que bien, me alegra mucho!